# success does not appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Help to make a conclusion successful transmission of data. I tried in different ways, but it does not work. By clicking on the "Send" button the data is sent, but the message "Data sent successfully".
I need it to form disappeared and instead of it there was a message "Data sent successfully"

```
    submitHandler: function(form){
        var $form = $(form);
        $.post('form.php', $form.serialize(), function(data){
            if (!data || data.status !== 'ok') {
                $form.find('input').addClass('error');
                return false;
            }
            forms.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('.form--success').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    }
});
```

form.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $headers = "From: $phone<$mail>\r\n";
    $body = "From: $phone<$mail>\r\n Phone Number: $phone\n E-Mail:      $mail\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    exit();
 }
```

http://37.230.210.96/ - testing site

Comment: You have `forms.fadeOut`. Did you mean `form.fadeOut` or `$form.fadeOut`?

Comment: Change to $form.fadeOut or form.fadeOut - the same result, nothing happens.

Comment: Is the form getting the class `error` at all?

Comment: It displays an error checkbox. Look at all the code in the test site, will understand what's what. init.js

Comment: It might be because the php isn't outputting anything, so `data` is empty and therefore triggering `if (!data)`. See if something like `echo 'ok';` right before the `exit();` in the php file gets it working

Comment: No. Same ... Most likely the script can not find the block (form--success)

Comment: Well you said it displays an error checkbox. That should only be happening because of the if statement. It wouldn't even be getting down to the part with `.form--success` if the error checkbox is there. However, are you sure that `form--success` is exactly how it is on that element? And is it a class or the id? Because that makes a difference.

Comment: This is the class. It does not give an opportunity to click on the "send" button, if not checked (Accept)

Comment: Could you possibly post the relevant html into your question?

Answer (score 1):

You're not targeting the right element to fade out. You have:

```
var form = $(form);
```

To fade that out you would use this:

```
form.fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('.form--success').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

`forms` != `form`

Comment: Can you give more details @eNkee? Is there an error?